# Messages from audioWorklet processor console.log are not displayed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Browser:

Chromium
Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)

I took the audioWorklet example
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/basic/hello-audio-worklet/

main.js

```
  // Copyright (c) 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
    // Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
    // found in the LICENSE file.

    const audioContext = new AudioContext();

    const startAudio = async (context) => {
        await context.audioWorklet.addModule('bypass-processor.js');
        const oscillator = new OscillatorNode(context);
        const bypasser = new AudioWorkletNode(context, 'bypass-processor');
        oscillator.connect(bypasser).connect(context.destination);
        oscillator.start();
    };

    // A simplem onLoad handler. It also handles user gesture to unlock the audio
    // playback.
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        const buttonEl = document.getElementById('button-start');
        buttonEl.disabled = false;
        buttonEl.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            await startAudio(audioContext);
            audioContext.resume();
            buttonEl.disabled = true;
            buttonEl.textContent = 'Playing...';
        }, false);
    });
```

Processor.js

```
// Copyright (c) 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/**
 * A simple bypass node demo.
 *
 * @class BypassProcessor
 * @extends AudioWorkletProcessor
 */
class BypassProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    process(inputs, outputs) {
        // By default, the node has single input and output.
        const input = inputs[0];
        const output = outputs[0];

        console.log('I CAN SEE THIS MESSAGE', output)
        for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {
            output[channel].set(input[channel]);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('bypass-processor', BypassProcessor);
```

I tried to find a solution on the Internet, but such a problem does not seem to exist.
Data should be output to devTool

AudioContext connects

How can I make sure that the processor is connected?

What do I need to enable for them to appear?

Comment: `AudioWorklet` runs in own thread, other DevTools should be attached to the worklet to debug its code and watch console messages.

Comment: And which ones exactly? It worked for me before updating chrome

Comment: Why not ask it there https://issues.chromium.org/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:1457055&s=created_time:desc&pli=1? You get an answer there faster.

Comment: There is this issue: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/327027138
Status is in progress